# Unable to send email out on port 25 which was previously working

Tags: networking, server, email, postfix

Hello I am having issue sending mail from my own hosted mail server. I has worked fine for a long time.
A few days ago I added DKIM using an online guide, everything seemed fine at first.
About 18 hours later a problem arose where my system cannot send any mail out at all, all incoming mail is OK, outgoing mail sits in the queue and never gets delivered.
I have backed out all the changes for the DKIM (including removing the DNS entry) and waited two days for the changes to work their way around, the problem still exists.
Diagnostics and testing has come up with the following…

Testing with telnet as follows:

Local, testing works ok:  `telnet 127.0.0.1 25`  - I can see the connection in my postfix log

Testing to any remote mail system I get the following:

```
:> telnet alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
Trying 74.125.200.26...
Connected to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
ehlo googlemail.com
```

After this it does nothing at all until it times out or I break with `^]`
Typing anything here achieves nothing. (typed characters are not shown)

As a comparison, from another system the same test....

```
:> telnet alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
Trying 74.125.200.27...
Connected to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP g68-20020a636b47000000b005e468d36711si11132873pgc.652 - gsmtp
ehlo googlemail.com
250-mx.google.com at your service, [2.100.131.82]
250-SIZE 157286400
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
```

I did telnet testing from my mail server to another system I have available…
Using telnet on the mail server and listening on the port with `nc -l -p` on the other server, I can create a `telnet` connection and see the characters I type on the other system

Mail server:  `telnet <ip of test computer> 55`

Test computer: `nc -l -p 55`

This connected fine and when I type in telnet the characters appear on the test computer – I first did this test in on port 55 to prove the tactic, when trying exactly the same test on port 25 –it does not work.

The odd thing is, if I telnet to port 25 without first starting the listen on the test computer, the telnet does not connect so it can see there is nothing listening on the port, when it I am listening on the port it does connect, but then cannot send any data.
I have tried disabling my firewalls, stopping and clearing fail2ban and clearing my iptables, (with numerous reboots) none of these have helped.

Something seems to be interfering or blocking outbound traffic on port 25, but I can’t find it and have no idea why it has suddenly started happening.